# jQuery callbacks cumulation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a simple jQuery plugin called magicForm (How ridiculous is this?). Now face to a problem that I think I'm not figuring out properly.

My plugin is supposed to be applied on a container element, that will show each of its inputs one by one as user fills them. That's not the exact purpose of my problem. 
Each time I initialize the container, I declare an event click callback. Let me show an example.

```js
(function($){
  var methods = {
    init: function(options){
      return this.each(function(){
        var form, inputs;

        var settings = {
          debug: false
        };
        settings = $.extend(settings, options);
        form = $(this);

        $('a.submit', form).on('click', function(event){
          if (settings.submitCallback) {
            settings.submitCallback.call(form, inputs);
          }
          return false;
        });
      });
    },
    reset: function() {

    }
  }

  $.fn.magicForm = function(method) {
    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist.' );
    }
  };
})($);
```

I'm focusing on a specific part of this code :

```js
$('a.submit', form).on('click', function(event){
    if (settings.submitCallback) {
        settings.submitCallback.call(form, inputs);
    }
    return false;
});
```

Because each time the `init` method is called, that poor callback is registered.

I was experiencing this painfully, when I invoked my plugin on an element nested in a twitter bootstrap 'tab', nested itself in a bootstrap modal :
I was calling `init` each time the event 'shown' of my bootstrap modal was triggered.

So, this is how I fixed it in my `init` method :

```js
// Prevent callback cumulation
if (!$(this).data('form_initialized')) {
    $('a.submit', form).on('click', function(event){
        if (settings.submitCallback) {
            settings.submitCallback.call(form, inputs);
        }
        return false;
    });
    $(this).data('form_initialized', true);
}
```

And I'm far from feeling sure about this.

Thank your for your time !

Comment: What is "cumuation"? I assume you mean "cumulation"?

Comment: Yes I apologize, I fixed it

Comment: Don't apologize, i was being a smart-ass. I should apologize to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many jquery plugins use `data` to know if their plugins were initialized.  Most often, they use the name of their own plugin as a part (or in whole) as the data.  For example:

`$(this).data('magicForm')`

So your approach of using that to signal is not a bad one.

However, you have two other options:

1) Pull the event handler out so the handler is a single instance.  Above your methods, do `var fnOnSubmit = function() { ... }`  Then you can simply ensure proper binding by calling `$('a.submit', form).unbind('click', fnOnSubmit)` before rebinding it the way you are already doing it.

2) Another option is to use event namespaces.

`$('a.submit', form).unbind('click.magicForm');` then rebinding it with `.on('click.magicForm')`  This namespace approach ensures that when you unbind it only unbinds in the context of your namespace magicForm, thus leaving all other click events (e.g. from other plugins) intact.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could first explicitely remove the click-handler:

```
$('a.submit', form).off('click').on('click', function(event){ ... })
```

However, I would suggest you use event namespacing to prevent **all** click handlers (even those perhaps set by code not your own) from being removed:

```
$('a.submit', form).off('click.magicForm').on('click.magicForm', function(event){ ... })
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid the unbind way, but the namespaced way seems right.